# How to pass *struct*ured data from libGDX to openGL shader?

Tags: opengl, shader, data-structure

I know about the standard methods to pass floats, ints, or vectors. However, I'm curious whether there is an elegant way to pass data from libGDX Java code directly into a shader struct.

I'm looking for a libGDX method to pass a whole structure *or* best practice examples on how to pass structured data in case libGDX does not support this natively.